# c++ - How to split a given string from input to different types of variables?

Tags: c++

I want to be able to get a line and split it to different types of variables (using standard c++ libraries). So this input line:

```
C 56 99.7 86.7 9000
```

Will "explode" by a space char to these variables in order:

```
Char
std:string
double
double
double
```

This is how I currently handle the given input:

```
#define MAX_LINE 200

char line[MAX_LINE];
cout << "Enter the line: ";
cin.getline (line,MAX_LINE);
```

Is there some special function like `getline()` i can use to separate the given input and assign these input to variables (with casting or similar)?

Comment: Read further on in your C++ book. It teaches you about formatted extraction from streams.

Comment: Tokenize you string and after, using some try/catch blocks convert into desired data tyoes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `>>` operator to get what you want

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char c;
    double d;
    std::cin >> c >> d;

    std::cout << "The char was: " << c << ", the double was:" << d;    
}
```

You can read more about it [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using getline(), use istream operator >>.

These are the overloads for this operator:

```
// Member functions  :

istream& operator>> (bool& val );
istream& operator>> (short& val );
istream& operator>> (unsigned short& val );
istream& operator>> (int& val );
istream& operator>> (unsigned int& val );
istream& operator>> (long& val );
istream& operator>> (unsigned long& val );
istream& operator>> (float& val );
istream& operator>> (double& val );
istream& operator>> (long double& val );
istream& operator>> (void*& val );
istream& operator>> (streambuf* sb );
istream& operator>> (istream& ( *pf )(istream&));
istream& operator>> (ios& ( *pf )(ios&));
istream& operator>> (ios_base& ( *pf )(ios_base&));

// Global functions :
istream& operator>> (istream& is, char& ch );
istream& operator>> (istream& is, signed char& ch );
istream& operator>> (istream& is, unsigned char& ch );
istream& operator>> (istream& is, char* str );
istream& operator>> (istream& is, signed char* str );
istream& operator>> (istream& is, unsigned char* str );

char ch;
std:string str;
double d;

cin >> ch >> str >> d;
```

Comment: You could have just given the link instead of writing them all over.